# How do I adjust things in 3d in after effects

Tags: after-effects, 3d

I have multiple layers I now wish edit them in 3 dimensions. So I check the 3d layer attribute, but I still cant move the elements in that layer. In a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kD73GVXwLXg) (7:45) i have been following, when the user clicks on the 3d layer option, an axis appears on the the element, and it can be enlarged and moved.

See picture:

[image]

However no such axis appears when I check the 3d layer option. Do I need to enable it somewhere in the options?

Comment: My after effects is acting really weird, I can't select things using the selection tool anymore, or i can, but there is no visible marker telling me i have selected it, i cant see where my anchor point is either.

Answer (score 1):

I pressed CTRL + SHIFT + H and my controls were back

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your toggle mask / path visibility was off?

[image: Try this button.]